# Debugging JNLP Application

Tags: java, debugging, jnlp, java-web-start

I want to debug a JNLP application. I am using the below to launch it.

**javaws -verbose -J-Xdebug -J-Xnoagent -J-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=8989 myjnlp.jnlp**

I think due to a "double launch" described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javaws/developersguide/troubleshooting.03.06.html), a new VM is launched, which is not taking my debug parameters.

I am able to connect to the first VM(since its in suspend=y), but within seconds that application ends, and a new instance of java is launched and its not in debug.
This is what i see in the console (personal info removed with ...)

*Could not launch from cache. Will try online mode. [Some of required resources are not cached.]
Creating temporary directory: C:\DOCUME~1...\LOCALS~1\Temp\FrontendApplication-8.2.1.0-...
Creating installation directory: C:\DOCUME~1...\LOCALS~1\Temp\FrontendApplication-8.2.1.0-...\install
localVersion: 20120409141901452
appVersion: 20120409141901452
New version available: false
Downloading archives...
pluginDir is C:\DOCUME~1...\LOCALS~1\Temp\FrontendApplication-8.2.1.0-...\install\plugins
Framework: C:\DOCUME~1...\LOCALS~1\Temp\FrontendApplication-8.2.1.0-...\install\plugins\org.eclipse.osgi_3.6.2.R36x_v20110210.jar
Invoking starter...*

Comment: Similar questions already exist in the forum, but there answer is not helping me. I also tried using the http url of the jnlp file,but no effect.